# LaTeX: csvsimple package errors with all comands

Tags: latex

I wanted to set a longtable in LaTeX with the csvsimple package. I think I included everything right, but I am still getting a "! Undefined control sequence" error.

I tried to compile just the code below in an separate file, but it didn't work too.

I'm working with Texmaker 5.0.3 and PDFlatex to compile.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotlongtable[separator=pipe]{foo.csv}
\end{document}
```

The complete error message is:

```latex
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError ...
#4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
l.234 ...tabular[separator=pipe]{foo.csv}
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

The command should be `\csvautolongtable` instead of `\csvautotlongtable` and the `longtable` package is missing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\csvautolongtable[separator=pipe]{foo.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @BlueStst Can you include a short sample document for foo.cvs to test? https://www.overleaf.com/read/sjydmfthsyvm works fine

Comment: Montage|Grabsteineffekt|Fehlerhafte/ keine Funktion der Baugruppe|Unsymmetrisches Lot|Lotdepots überprüfen|5|3|1|15
|||Großes Temperaturgefälle im Konvektionsofen|Temperaturkurve überprüfen|5|2|1|10
Montage|Lot verschoben dispenst|Kein Kontakt, Kurzschlussbildung|Ungenaues Arbeiten|Genauer arbeiten|4|4|2|32

Didn't find the upload button:'D

Comment: @BlueStst Please add it as codeblock to your question, otherwise linebreaks are  not preserved.

Comment: @BlueStst The problem seems to be the Umlaute in `überprüfen`. With `uberprufen` it works